# How to convert string to array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a chart using High charts. my series data is coming from database through controller in MVC. I am storing the output in string variable. I need to convert this  string variable to  Array object. kindly help me to do it. My string variable output is

```
{name: "2019",data:[3883,3961,3893,3780,4021,3765,3560,4099,3310,3403,3628,3137,]},
{name: "2020",data:[3489,3883,3403,3331,2605,1546,]}
```

I have tried to use JSON.parse and $.parseJSON commands but its not working. It is giving me error as "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"
Kindly anybody help me to solve the problem. I am stuck for  this since last 5 days.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: I used this but it is giving syntax error as i mentioned in my post.

Comment: You should store the output as JSON, then this would be easy.

Comment: Hi Nick, If i am taking this output and assigning directly into the array variable. it works perfectly. If this is not  valid JSON then kindly advice how to format the data so that i can  convert it to array.

Comment: Fix whatever is giving you that output, because it's not valid JSON as has been pointed out to you.

Comment: It's not a valid JSON. But if you need to parse exactly the same structure use something like this `let resutl=source.split(",").map(v=JSON.parse(v))`

Comment: let resutl=source.split(",").map(v=JSON.parse(v));   This whole thing is a command?

Comment: @MAK can you add the code of the controller, request and response headers? If using Node.js with express on backend did you set `express.json()` as top-level middleware?

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()` create the json instead of whatever you are doing currently

Comment: Dangling commas are not allowed in JSON, while it's totally valid syntax for JavaScript. Remove it, and this particular data will become valid JSON.

Comment: @krassx The dangling commas aren't the only thing keeping this from validating as JSON.

Comment: Yes. And result1 will contain list of object parsed by json

Comment: Why is your output formatted so poorly? You shouldn't create JSON yourself use in-built functions for that. For example in PHP just use `json_encode($variable)` and convert your variable to JSON. In currently returned string you have 2 seperate objects, but they should be nested in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as many have said is that you do not have a valid JSON string. There are three things you need to fix.

1. Wrap your variable names in quotes.
2. Remove the hanging commas in your data value.
3. Wrap the entire thing in array square brackets.

In the end, your JSON string should look like this:

```
[{"name": "2019","data":[3883,3961,3893,3780,4021,3765,3560,4099,3310,3403,3628,3137]},{"name": "2020","data":[3489,3883,3403,3331,2605,1546]}]
```

Once you can produce a string that looks like a valid JSON, you can use the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to produce an iterable object. Like so:

```
var myJSON = JSON.parse('[{"name": "2019","data":[3883,3961,3893,3780,4021,3765,3560,4099,3310,3403,3628,3137]},{"name": "2020","data":[3489,3883,3403,3331,2605,1546]}]');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for  the support from all of you. specially  rosy Town. Many many thanks. now it is working perfectly.